# PHP - Can not display the results by key in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my code:

```
$stack = array();
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
       $PID = $item->getProduct()->getId();
        $stack["productid"][] = $PID;
        $QTY = $item->getQty();
        $stack["productqty"][] = $QTY;

}


foreach($stack as $value){
 $ProductId = $value["productid"];
 $ProductQty = $value["productqty"];
 echo "ProductId is: $ProductId - Product QTY is: $ProductQty <br>";
}
```

I receive two rows as the exact number of results is but `$ProductId` and `$ProductQty` seems to be blank.

Where is my mistake why i can not display the results by key?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the array structure of `$stack`

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Use this code : foreach($stack as $key => $value){  }

Comment: Can you please make a complete answer so i can test and mark it ?

Comment: Please post your full code with query

Answer (score 2):

```
 if(!empty($stack) && count($stack)>0)
 {
     foreach($stack['productid'] as $key=>$value){
         $ProductId = $value;
         $ProductQty = $stack["productqty"][$key];
         echo "ProductId is: $ProductId - Product QTY is: $ProductQty <br>";
     }
 }
```

Use this code..

Answer (score 0):

You just try with below code

```
foreach($stack as $value){
     $ProductId = $value[0];
    $ProductQty = $value[1];
    echo "ProductId is: $ProductId - Product QTY is: $ProductQty <br>";
 }
```

**The reason is, in the first iteration, the `$value` will contain the value of `$stack["productid"]`. So that `$value["productid"]` won't work. You have to give the index `0`. And for the `$ProductQty` you have to give index `1`**

Comment: Not working. the result is: `ProductId is: 30029 - Product QTY is: 30030 
ProductId is: 1 - Product QTY is: 3 ` which is not corect. QTY for the first item is 1, for the second is 3.

Comment: @TonyStark, What is result of `print_r($stack)`??

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. it will help full....

```
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $stack[] = array('productid'=>$item->getProduct()->getId(),'productqty'=>$item->getQty());
}

foreach($stack as $value){ 

     $ProductId = $value["productid"];
     $ProductQty = $value["productqty"];
     echo "ProductId is: $ProductId - Product QTY is: $ProductQty <br>";

}
```